# HttpServletRequest return emty reader

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

in **HttpServletRequest** when I get the request in the controller,
I can see headers and parameters of the request. but when I use

```
ContentCachingRequestWrapper contentCachingRequestWrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);

String requestBody = new String(contentCachingRequestWrapper.getContentAsByteArray());
```

its return empty String body.

also, I use the below code

```
bufferedReader =  request.getReader();

char[] charBuffer = new char[128];

int bytesRead;
while ( (bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) != -1 ) {
  sb.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

and I got the same result.

regards.

Comment: You only read the request body, not the headers/parameters.

Comment: @dan1st

please read the question completely, when I get the body from the request using **HttpServletRequest** it is empty but I send complete body in request and it will map on my class using ```@RequestBody``` but in **HttpServletRequest** its empty.
I remark ```@RequestBody``` and class on the controller method to test **HttpServletRequest** body but it is empty yet.